# Updating data of an array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

What i am trying to do is to make a simple app from where a user can edit his availability on weekdays. the code is working fine.. i am fetching the data from select box but the problem when i am trying to update data of monday the tuesday data is also updating with the same value of monday**(as you can see in the last view)**

my db JSON

```
"doctorSchedule" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "working_day" : "Monday",
            "working_from" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "hours" : "9",
                    "minutes" : "30"
                }
            ],
            "working_to" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "hours" : "6",
                    "minutes" : "30"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "working_day" : "Tue",
            "working_from" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "hours" : "9",
                    "minutes" : "30"
                }
            ],
            "working_to" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "hours" : "6",
                    "minutes" : "30"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

My Angular code.

```
$scope.data1 = $stateParams.viewUser;
$http({ 
    url: "/getinfo",
    method: "POST",
    headers :{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'},
    data: dataParam    
}).success(function(response) { 
    if(response.status_code == "worked") {
      $scope.viewUser = response.clinicUserVo;
      $scope.datasc = response.doctorSchedule;                              
    } 
});
```

My HTML file

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="docSchedule in data1.doctorSchedule">
<tr>  <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="data1.working_day"></th>
                                            <td>{{docSchedule.working_day}}</td>
                                            <td>

            <select  id="user_time_zone"   class="form-control form-group" ng-model="data1.working_from">

                                    <option value="" >{{docSchedule.working_from[0].hours}}</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="01" >01</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="02" >02</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="03" >03</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="04" >04</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="06" >06</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="07" >07</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="08" >08</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="09" >09</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="11" >11</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="12" >12</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="13" >13</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="14" >14</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="16" >16</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="17" >17</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="18" >18</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="19" >19</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="21" >21</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="22" >22</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="23" >23</option>
  </select>

                                                <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <select  id="user_time_zone"  class="form-control form-group"  ng-model="data1.working_from"> 
                            <option value="" disabled="disabled">{{docSchedule.working_from[0].minutes}}</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="25" >25</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="30" >30</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="35" >35</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="40" >40</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="45" >45</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="50" >50</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="55" >55</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><b>to</b></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                                     <select  id="user_time_zone"  class="form-control form-group"  ng-model="data1.working_to" name="user_time_zone">
                                                    <option value="" disabled="disabled">{{docSchedule.working_to[0].hours}}</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="25" >25</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="30" >30</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="35" >35</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="40" >40</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="45" >45</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="50" >50</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="55" >55</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><b>:</b></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                                <select  id="user_time_zone" class="form-control  form-group"  ng-model="data1.working_to"  name="user_time_zone">
                                                    <option value="" disabled="disabled">{{docSchedule.working_to[0].minutes}}</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="01" >01</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="02" >02</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="o3" >03</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="04" >04</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="06" >06</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="07" >07</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="08" >08</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="09" >09</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="11" >11</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="12" >12</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="13" >13</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="14" >14</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="16" >16</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="17" >17</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="18" >18</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="19" >19</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="21" >21</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="22" >22</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="23" >23</option>
                                                </select>

                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>






                                 <tr>

</tr>
<tr >


</table>
```

HTML VIEW

See in this html page when i am trying to updatemonday data and the tue data is also automatically changing how can i solve it through Angular?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<select  id="user_time_zone"   class="form-control form-group" ng-model="data1.working_from">`

to

`<select  id="user_time_zone"   class="form-control form-group" ng-model="docSchedule.working_from">`

Because that way, each `select` of each `ng-reapeat` will point its data to the respective `docSchedule`.

Understood? Saying with other words, your code doesn't work as expected because `data1.working_from` points to the same model in every scopes, in every `ng-repeat`'s.

Comment: but not sure if i would able to pass the array with docSchedule.working_from

Comment: You probably will have the review the way you have formatted your models. But at least you can solve that problem of "change one cause change on other"

Comment: yes absolutely that problem is no more.. but as you can see i also want to update specific data in that array form.. can you please help me out with that?

Comment: `working_from` and `working_to` needs to be an array? It couldn't be an object directly? Like `working_from: { _id: null, hours: 9 }` for example?

Comment: By doing that (changing from array to object), you could do inside the select something like: `ng-model="docSchedule.working_from.hour"` for the `hour` select, and the same logic for `minute`